# how to use setpixel function in bitmap

Tags: c#

hi i'm traying to use set pixel method but it is not working 
i'm traying to convert an integer value and convert it to color but the set pixel is not taking any value the color remains zero

```
  for (int l = 0; l < image1.Height; l++)
            for (int k = 0; k < w1; k++)
            {


              int red = (depth[l,k])%255;
              int green = (depth[l,k])%255; 
              int blue = (depth[l,k])%255; 

             mybitmap.SetPixel(l, k,Color.FromArgb(0,red,green,blue));

            }
        pictureBox1.Image= mybitmap;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your alpha component is 0, which means fully transparent. Try 255 instead:

```
mybitmap.SetPixel(l, k,Color.FromArgb(255,red,green,blue));
```

Think of `alpha` as *opacity*, not *transparency*, and the numbers will make a little more sense.